# My google maps Latitude and Longitude is changing not the Location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

[when i load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkxIc.png)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=hgter...&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {

        center: {

            lat: 12.971599,

            lng: 77.594563

        },

        zoom: 15

    });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position: {

        lat: 12.971599,

        lng: 77.594563

    },

    map: map,

    draggable: true

});

var searchBox = new

google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('searchmap'));
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var i, place;

    for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {

        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    map.setZoom(15);

});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {

    var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();

    var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

    $('#lat').val(lat);

    $('#lng').val(lng);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will Keep in my mind try to edit the above question!!!@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

When you move your marker, you  change your lat and lng input value, that's ok.

But what you call "location" (i guess your #searchmap input) has no link with it. If you want to replace it you need Reverse Geocoding :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse?hl=fr

You give lat+lng, reverse geocoding answer with the location found at this place.

Comment: Yeah, #searchmap input has no link with it...wt i need is as the marker moves the location should be change dynamically in the Map input box as shown in image..so what changes should i make for #searchmap tell me....

Comment: I told you in the answer, you need reverse geocoding, look at the link in the answer. Reverse geocoding give you location name for any lat+lng ; tha'ts what you need.